# How long are Pandas groupby objects remembered?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following example Python 3.4 script. It does the following:

1. creates a dataframe,
2. converts the date variable to datetime64 format,
3. creates a groupby object based on two categorical variables,
4. produces a dataframe that contains a count of the number items in each group,
5. merges count dataframe back with original dataframe to create a column containing the number of rows in each group
6. creates a column containing the difference in dates between sequential rows.

Here is the script:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Create dataframe consisting of id, date and two categories (gender and age)
tempDF = pd.DataFrame({ 'id': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20],
                        'date': ["02/04/2015 02:34","06/04/2015 12:34","09/04/2015 23:03","12/04/2015 01:00","15/04/2015 07:12","21/04/2015 12:59","29/04/2015 17:33","04/05/2015 10:44","06/05/2015 11:12","10/05/2015 08:52","12/05/2015 14:19","19/05/2015 19:22","27/05/2015 22:31","01/06/2015 11:09","04/06/2015 12:57","10/06/2015 04:00","15/06/2015 03:23","19/06/2015 05:37","23/06/2015 13:41","27/06/2015 15:43"],
                        'gender': ["male","female","female","male","male","female","female",np.nan,"male","male","female","male","female","female","male","female","male","female",np.nan,"male"],
                        'age': ["young","old","old","old","old","old",np.nan,"old","old","young","young","old","young","young","old",np.nan,"old","young",np.nan,np.nan]})

# Convert date to datetime
tempDF['date'] = pd.to_datetime(tempDF['date'])

# Create groupby object based on two categorical variables
tempGroupby = tempDF.sort_values(['gender','age','id']).groupby(['gender','age'])

# Count number in each group and merge with original dataframe to create 'count' column
tempCountsDF = tempGroupby['id'].count().reset_index(drop=False)
tempCountsDF = tempCountsDF.rename(columns={'id': 'count'})
tempDF = tempDF.merge(tempCountsDF, on=['gender','age'])

# Calculate difference between consecutive rows in each group. (First row in each
# group should have date difference = NaT)
tempGroupby = tempDF.sort_values(['gender','age','id']).groupby(['gender','age'])
tempDF['diff'] = tempGroupby['date'].diff()
print(tempDF)
```

This script produces the following output:

```
      age                date  gender  id  count                diff
0   young 2015-02-04 02:34:00    male   1      2                 NaT
1   young 2015-10-05 08:52:00    male  10      2   243 days 06:18:00
2     old 2015-06-04 12:34:00  female   2      3                 NaT
3     old 2015-09-04 23:03:00  female   3      3    92 days 10:29:00
4     old 2015-04-21 12:59:00  female   6      3 -137 days +13:56:00
5     old 2015-12-04 01:00:00    male   4      6                 NaT
6     old 2015-04-15 07:12:00    male   5      6 -233 days +06:12:00
7     old 2015-06-05 11:12:00    male   9      6    51 days 04:00:00
8     old 2015-05-19 19:22:00    male  12      6  -17 days +08:10:00
9     old 2015-04-06 12:57:00    male  15      6  -44 days +17:35:00
10    old 2015-06-15 03:23:00    male  17      6    69 days 14:26:00
11  young 2015-12-05 14:19:00  female  11      4                 NaT
12  young 2015-05-27 22:31:00  female  13      4 -192 days +08:12:00
13  young 2015-01-06 11:09:00  female  14      4 -142 days +12:38:00
14  young 2015-06-19 05:37:00  female  18      4   163 days 18:28:00
```

And this exactly what I'd expect. However, it seems to rely on creating the groupby object twice (in exactly the same way). If the second groupby definition is commented out, it seems to lead to a very different output in the diff column:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Create dataframe consisting of id, date and two categories (gender and age)
tempDF = pd.DataFrame({ 'id': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20],
                        'date': ["02/04/2015 02:34","06/04/2015 12:34","09/04/2015 23:03","12/04/2015 01:00","15/04/2015 07:12","21/04/2015 12:59","29/04/2015 17:33","04/05/2015 10:44","06/05/2015 11:12","10/05/2015 08:52","12/05/2015 14:19","19/05/2015 19:22","27/05/2015 22:31","01/06/2015 11:09","04/06/2015 12:57","10/06/2015 04:00","15/06/2015 03:23","19/06/2015 05:37","23/06/2015 13:41","27/06/2015 15:43"],
                        'gender': ["male","female","female","male","male","female","female",np.nan,"male","male","female","male","female","female","male","female","male","female",np.nan,"male"],
                        'age': ["young","old","old","old","old","old",np.nan,"old","old","young","young","old","young","young","old",np.nan,"old","young",np.nan,np.nan]})

# Convert date to datetime
tempDF['date'] = pd.to_datetime(tempDF['date'])

# Create groupby object based on two categorical variables
tempGroupby = tempDF.sort_values(['gender','age','id']).groupby(['gender','age'])

# Count number in each group and merge with original dataframe to create 'count' column
tempCountsDF = tempGroupby['id'].count().reset_index(drop=False)
tempCountsDF = tempCountsDF.rename(columns={'id': 'count'})
tempDF = tempDF.merge(tempCountsDF, on=['gender','age'])

# Calculate difference between consecutive rows in each group. (First row in each
# group should have date difference = NaT)
# ****** THIS TIME THE FOLLOWING GROUPBY DEFINITION IS COMMENTED OUT ***** 
# tempGroupby = tempDF.sort_values(['gender','age','id']).groupby(['gender','age'])
tempDF['diff'] = tempGroupby['date'].diff()
print(tempDF)
```

And, this time the output is very different (and NOT what I wanted at all)

```
      age                date  gender  id  count                diff
0   young 2015-02-04 02:34:00    male   1      2                 NaT
1   young 2015-10-05 08:52:00    male  10      2                 NaT
2     old 2015-06-04 12:34:00  female   2      3    92 days 10:29:00
3     old 2015-09-04 23:03:00  female   3      3                 NaT
4     old 2015-04-21 12:59:00  female   6      3 -233 days +06:12:00
5     old 2015-12-04 01:00:00    male   4      6 -137 days +13:56:00
6     old 2015-04-15 07:12:00    male   5      6                 NaT
7     old 2015-06-05 11:12:00    male   9      6                 NaT
8     old 2015-05-19 19:22:00    male  12      6    51 days 04:00:00
9     old 2015-04-06 12:57:00    male  15      6   243 days 06:18:00
10    old 2015-06-15 03:23:00    male  17      6                 NaT
11  young 2015-12-05 14:19:00  female  11      4  -17 days +08:10:00
12  young 2015-05-27 22:31:00  female  13      4 -192 days +08:12:00
13  young 2015-01-06 11:09:00  female  14      4 -142 days +12:38:00
14  young 2015-06-19 05:37:00  female  18      4  -44 days +17:35:00
```

(In my real-life script the results seem to be a little erratic, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. But in the above script, the different outputs seem to occur consistently.)

Why is it necessary to recreate the groupby object on what is, essentially, the same dataframe (albeit with an additional column added) immediately before using the .diff() function? This seems very dangerous to me.

Comment: You've altered ``tempDF``, and the second ``groupby`` is computed on the altered dataframe. I suspect that's why the results of the two are different.

Answer (score 2):

Not the same, the index has changed. For example:

```
tempDF.loc[1].id  # before

10

tempDF.loc[1].id  # after

2
```

So if you compute `tempGroupby` with the old `tempDF` and then change the indexes in `tempDF` when you do this:

```
tempDF['diff'] = tempGroupby['date'].diff()
```

the indexes do not match as you expect. You are assigning to each row the difference corresponding to the row that had that index in the old `tempDF`.

Comment: Thanks Goyo. That's certainly pointed me in the right direction. When I used .merge(), I thought the index would be preserved but, when joining columns on columns (as I'm doing by using on=[] in the merge function), the indices are ignored (I've just found that in the docs). It's only when joining index to index or index to column that the index is preserved.